# C call stack uses "ebp" to visit variables, then "esp" seems redundant?

Tags: function, assembly, x86, stack-frame, stack-pointer

C function uses call stack(stack frame) to push/pop registers before/after function call. If ebp is the frame pointer that's used to visit all variables on stack, then seems esp is redundant?

Then why in prolog/epilog of a function call, we operate both esp and ebp?
If I use only one register to do this job, any inconvenient places?

Thanks.

Comment: ebp keeps track of the current stack frame, esp keeps track of the top of stack. ebp is the one that's technically not needed, but if you're hand-writing assembly, it's much easier to use both.

Comment: call/ret is still based on esp, so even if you only use ebp-based addressing, you always have to drag esp along anyway.

Comment: If you have a question about the code generation of your C compiler then you need to mention its name and show the compile options you used.  Standard mistake is to look at non-optimized code.  In general, a half-decent compiler will push esp because it is going to be used in a subsequent call anyway and will eliminate ebp in a leaf function.